# Compound adjectives for the following

Tags: adjectives

I have to form compound adjectives for

> a) intolerant (mind)
>   b) pleasing (warm)
>   c) sensible (head)
>   d) mean (fist)
>   e) intelligent (wit)
>   f) scary (raise)

but I couldn't do it. The example I'm given is *artificial* (*make*) =  *man-made*.

I've checked the dictionaries but I can't get how to form the compound adjectives.

Comment: Did you come up with any attempts that didn't seem to be right?

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted the question. I didn't get the straight idea on how to form the compound adjective.

Comment: Yes, but what were they?

Answer (score 1):

> a) intollerant - ***narrow-minded***
>
> b) pleasing - ***heart-warming***
>
> c) sensible - ***hard-headed***
>
> d) mean - ***tight-fisted***
>
> e) intelligent - ***quick-witted***
>
> f) scary - ***hair-raising***

Comment: Are the first and the second word synonyms? I'm sorry, I don't get well your answer, can you explain a little bit? Thank you.

Comment: Yeas, they are.

Comment: The first word is a word from your list. The next word is a compound noun which you are supposed to form. I highlighted them for clarity.

Comment: +1  very good answer. I think *sharp-witted* is also a word for that.